# IE 6 and Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, internet-explorer-6

Does Silverlight work with IE 6, are there any gotchas?

Just wondering if this is an alternative for customers stuck with IE 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For client OSs the answer is yes
More detail on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Silverlight#Operating_systems_and_web_browsers) about compatible OSs and browsers

Comment: Hi! I'm making a website now, and I have to choose between Flash and Silverlight. Is Silverlight automatically installed to 7 years old computers?

Comment: @50ndr33 It all depends on the browser version. Only IE8+ browsers ship with SL.

Answer (score 2):

I have worked on sites that run on IE6 and we were able to work well in Silverlight. As Silverlight is a Plugin, it doesn't matter what they underlying browser is, as long as it is the once supported by Silverlight team. We didnt come across any issues, we had worked on data driven app.

Comment: @JohnFx  
Hi! I'm making a website now, and I have to choose between Flash and Silverlight. Is Silverlight automatically installed to 7 years old computers?

Comment: Silverlight is not installed automatically. It is a browser plugin. So when user goes on a url, where silverlight plugin is needed to render the content, it will detect silverlight plugin is not installed and will show a standard installation message. You can view message and related details from this URL http://www.silverlight.net/learn/advanced-techniques/pre-loaders-and-installers/silverlight-install-and-upgrade-experience